# On starting a windows service, start threading. How can I accomplish this?

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-services, threadpool

I am creating a window service, but when it starts I want it create threads to keep pool/monitor of a ftp site. The issue I am facing, is when I try starting the service with a **while(true){}** inside which check for new files and then it should **ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem**, the service has a timeout issue when starting.

Comment: Can you provide some example code of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Could this be done as a Console app, running on a schedule via Windows Scheduler?

Comment: Where do you have your `while (true)` loop? Your service's "start" method needs to return right away, so of course putting an infinite loop in that method would be a bad idea. As DVK points out, without code, it's hard to comment on what's wrong with your code.

Comment: Please share your code.  In general, you should only perform setup/initialization on your OnStart event handler.  You can initiate multiple threads from the OnStart, but you don't want to do something inside an endless loop.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There should be no infinite while loop in the service OnStart method. That method should complete as soon as possible. Use it to setup the service threads/tasks but not to do anything that will block indefinitely.

Without any exception handling, thread pools, etc., here is how I used to do it (last time I wrote such a threaded service, which was 5 years ago, so no apologies if it is dated. Nowadays I try to use Task Parallel lib), NOTE to readers: I am simply demonstrating the idea, and snagged this from an old project. If you can do better, feel free to edit to improve this answer, or add your own answer.

```
public partial class GyrasoftMessagingService : ServiceBase
{

  protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
  {
     ThreadStart start = new ThreadStart(FaxWorker); // FaxWorker is where the work gets done
     Thread faxWorkerThread = new Thread(start);

     // set flag to indicate worker thread is active
     serviceStarted = true;

     // start threads
     faxWorkerThread.Start();
  }

  protected override void OnStop()
  {
     serviceStarted = false;
     // wait for threads to stop
     faxWorkerThread.Join(60);

     try
     {
        string error = "";
        Messaging.SMS.SendSMSTextAsync("5555555555", "Messaging Service stopped on " + System.Net.Dns.GetHostName(), ref error);
     }
     catch
     {
        // yes eat exception if text failed
     }
  }

  private static void FaxWorker()
  {
     // loop, poll and do work
  }


}
```